# How to put data to job scope Map inside the writer?

Tags: java, spring-batch

I start job following way:

```
jobExecution = jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);
jobExecution... /// I want to get Map with results here
```

Also I have following writer:

```
@Component
public class MyWriter implements ItemWriter<MyBean> {

    @Override
    public void write(@NonNull List<? extends MyBean> items) throws Exception {
             MyResult result = someComponent.doSmth(items);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to put result into Map to collect all results within single job execution.

How could I achieve it?

Comment: I'm not so good with Spring Batch, so I will let my colleague to know about your question. Also it doesn't look like your question has Spring Boot and Spring Integration scope. Therefore I have removed those tags.

Comment: @Artem Bilan thanks - agree with you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the result in the job execution context, something like:

```
@Component
public class MyWriter implements ItemWriter<MyBean> {

    private JobExecution jobExecution;

    @BeforeStep
    public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        jobExecution = stepExecution.getJobExecution();
    }

    @Override
    public void write(@NonNull List<? extends MyBean> items) throws Exception {
        MyResult result = someComponent.doSmth(items);
        jobExecution.getExecutionContext().put("result", result); // not sure how you are planning to use a map here
    }
}
```

Then get it from the execution context of the returned job execution:

```
jobExecution = jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);
// I want to get Map with results here
MyResult result = jobExecution.getExecutionContext().get("result");
```

Comment: Oh, it is very close to my aim. Actually my job contains partitioned step. So write method can be invoked in parallel in many threads. I want to collect all results in one place. I am not sure if it is safety if I will check map exist in execution context and then insert it if it doesn't exist. It is obvious race condition. So map should have following structure: Map<jobExecutionId, Map<StepExecutionId, Result>> . How could I achieve it?

Comment: Map<jobExecutionId, Map<StepExecutionId, List<Result>>>

Comment: Single List element contains Results of all chunks.

Comment: ok that's another story. Have you tried to make the writer thread safe? Otherwise you can try to put intermediate result of each partition in its step execution context then gather the results using a `StepExecutionAggregator`. I have a sample [here](https://github.com/benas/spring-batch-sandbox/tree/master/so53366710) that might help.

Comment: Actually my writer does http POST call so I think it is thread safe.

Comment: Thanks for example - I will investigate it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why and how exactly you want to collect the results in a `Map`, but if a `List` (that you could transform into a `Map` afterwards) would also do, then here's an idea:

Instead of invoking `someComponent.doSmth` in a custom `ItemWriter`, I would rather do that in an `ItemProcessor`'s `process` method (which processes only one item at a time, mind you), return the result, and then let a `ListItemWriter` receive all the results and store them in a `List` that you can access via method `ListItemWriter.getWrittenItems`.